# Merge JPA Entity using EntityHome from JBoss Seam

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, seam2

I am trying to update a entity using JBoss Seam and JPA, but I am facing the very common problem of Detached Entity. I will explain better.

I have a two simple entity that are related. This relations are mapped with annotations. Take a look:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "RATEIO", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "cd_projeto", "cd_tarefa", "cd_colaborador", "dt_rateio_inicial",
        "dt_rateio_final" }) })
@Audited
public class Rateio implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1564844894403478898L;

    private Long cdRateio;
    private Colaborador colaborador;
    private Tarefa tarefa;
    private Projeto projeto;
    private Date dtRateioInicial;
    private Date dtRateioFinal;

    private boolean flagAtividade;
    private TipoRateio tipo;
    private List<DetalheRateio> detalheRateios = new ArrayList<DetalheRateio>(0);

    public Rateio() {
    }

    public Rateio(Long cdRateio, Colaborador colaborador, Projeto projeto, Date dtRateioInicial, Date dtRateioFinal) {
        this.cdRateio = cdRateio;
        this.colaborador = colaborador;
        this.projeto = projeto;
        this.dtRateioInicial = dtRateioInicial;
        this.dtRateioFinal = dtRateioFinal;
    }

    public Rateio(Long cdRateio, Colaborador colaborador, Projeto projeto, Date dtRateioInicial, Date dtRateioFinal, List<DetalheRateio> detalheRateios) {
        this.cdRateio = cdRateio;
        this.colaborador = colaborador;
        this.projeto = projeto;
        this.dtRateioInicial = dtRateioInicial;
        this.dtRateioFinal = dtRateioFinal;
        this.detalheRateios = detalheRateios;
    }

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sg_RATEIO_SEQ", sequenceName = "RATEIO_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "sg_RATEIO_SEQ")
    @Column(name = "CD_RATEIO", nullable = false, scale = 0)
    public Long getCdRateio() {
        return this.cdRateio;
    }

    public void setCdRateio(Long cdRateio) {
        this.cdRateio = cdRateio;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CD_COLABORADOR", nullable = true)
    public Colaborador getColaborador() {
        return this.colaborador;
    }

    public void setColaborador(Colaborador colaborador) {
        this.colaborador = colaborador;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CD_PROJETO", nullable = true)
    public Projeto getProjeto() {
        return this.projeto;
    }

    public void setProjeto(Projeto projeto) {
        this.projeto = projeto;
    }

    @Column(name = "DT_RATEIO_INICIAL", nullable = false)
    public Date getDtRateioInicial() {
        return this.dtRateioInicial;
    }

    public void setDtRateioInicial(Date dtRateioInicial) {
        this.dtRateioInicial = dtRateioInicial;
    }

    @Column(name = "DT_RATEIO_FINAL", nullable = true)
    public Date getDtRateioFinal() {
        return this.dtRateioFinal;
    }

    public void setDtRateioFinal(Date dtRateioFinal) {
        this.dtRateioFinal = dtRateioFinal;
    }

    @OneToMany(targetEntity=DetalheRateio.class, mappedBy = "rateio")
    public List<DetalheRateio> getDetalheRateios() {
        return this.detalheRateios;
    }

    public void setDetalheRateios(List<DetalheRateio> detalheRateios) {
        this.detalheRateios = detalheRateios;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CD_TAREFA", nullable = true)
    public Tarefa getTarefa() {
        return tarefa;
    }

    public void setTarefa(Tarefa tarefa) {
        this.tarefa = tarefa;
    }

    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    public TipoRateio getTipo() {
        return tipo;
    }

    public void setTipo(TipoRateio tipo) {
        this.tipo = tipo;
    }

    @Transient
    public boolean isFlagAtividade() {
        return flagAtividade;
    }

    public void setFlagAtividade(boolean flagAtividade) {
        this.flagAtividade = flagAtividade;
    }
}
```

And my second entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DETALHE_RATEIO")
@Audited
public class DetalheRateio implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4109721744851677683L;

    private Long cdDetalheRateio;
    private Rateio rateio;
    private AtividadeOs atividadeOs;
    private float vlPorcentagem;

    public DetalheRateio() {
    }

    public DetalheRateio(Long cdDetalheRateio, Rateio rateio, AtividadeOs atividadeOs, float vlPorcentagem) {
        this.cdDetalheRateio = cdDetalheRateio;
        this.rateio = rateio;
        this.atividadeOs = atividadeOs;
        this.vlPorcentagem = vlPorcentagem;
    }

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sg_DET_RATEIO_SEQ", sequenceName = "DET_RATEIO_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "sg_DET_RATEIO_SEQ")
    @Column(name = "CD_DETALHE_RATEIO", nullable = false, scale = 0)
    public Long getCdDetalheRateio() {
        return this.cdDetalheRateio;
    }

    public void setCdDetalheRateio(Long cdDetalheRateio) {
        this.cdDetalheRateio = cdDetalheRateio;
    }

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Rateio.class, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CD_RATEIO", nullable = false)
    public Rateio getRateio() {
        return this.rateio;
    }

    public void setRateio(Rateio rateio) {
        this.rateio = rateio;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CD_ATIVIDADE_OS", nullable = false)
    public AtividadeOs getAtividadeOs() {
        return this.atividadeOs;
    }

    public void setAtividadeOs(AtividadeOs atividadeOs) {
        this.atividadeOs = atividadeOs;
    }

    @Column(name = "VL_PORCENTAGEM", nullable = false, precision = 19, scale = 2, columnDefinition = "NUMBER")
    public float getVlPorcentagem() {
        return this.vlPorcentagem;
    }

    public void setVlPorcentagem(float vlPorcentagem) {
        this.vlPorcentagem = vlPorcentagem;
    }
}
```

OK, so far, so good. Now, I have a class who extends [EntityHome](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.2.2.Final/api/org/jboss/seam/framework/EntityHome.html) from JBoss Seam, and is this class who tries to update my entity. Here is the code:

```
@Name("rateioHome")
public class RateioHome extends EntityHome<Rateio> {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public String update() {
        String result = null;
        boolean valid = true;
        if (getPercentualTotal().doubleValue() < 100 || instance.getDetalheRateios().size() < 2) {
            facesMessages.addFromResourceBundle(Severity.ERROR, "rateio.erro.atividade");
            valid = false;
        }

        if (instance.getDtRateioFinal() != null && instance.getDtRateioFinal().before(instance.getDtRateioInicial())) {
            facesMessages.addFromResourceBundle(Severity.ERROR, "rateio.erro.data");
            valid = false;
        }

        if (valid) {
            Rateio rateio = super.find();
            List<DetalheRateio> detalheRateios = getInstance().getDetalheRateios();
            List<DetalheRateio> detalheRateiosBd = rateio.getDetalheRateios();
            Map<Long, DetalheRateio> mapDetalheRateio = new HashMap<Long, DetalheRateio>();

            if (detalheRateiosBd != null && detalheRateiosBd.size() > 0) {

                Rateio _rateio = getInstance();

                for (DetalheRateio item : detalheRateiosBd) {

                    if (item.getCdDetalheRateio() != null) {

                        item.getRateio().setDtRateioInicial(_rateio.getDtRateioInicial());
                        item.getRateio().setDtRateioFinal(_rateio.getDtRateioFinal());
                        mapDetalheRateio.put(item.getCdDetalheRateio(), item);
                    }
                }
            }

            List<DetalheRateio> novos = (List<DetalheRateio>) CollectionUtils.subtract(detalheRateios, detalheRateiosBd);
            List<DetalheRateio> excluidos = (List<DetalheRateio>) CollectionUtils.subtract(detalheRateiosBd, detalheRateios);

            detalheRateiosBd.removeAll(excluidos);
            detalheRateiosBd.addAll(novos);

            setInstance(rateio);
            result = super.update();
            getEntityManager().flush();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Now, the problem. When I tr to update the entity on line: `result = super.update();`, I am facing this exception:

`javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: br.com.entity.DetalheRateio`

I tried to find a the method `merge` on EntityHome, but I have not found anything. This is a legacy code that I have to support and I am no expert on JBoss Seam. If you need more information, please, let me know.

Comment: merge() won't help as your Ratio entity is in fact managed. The error is complaining about a child DetalheRateio being detached. Perhaps you're adding a new instance somewhere without persisting it first?

Comment: Hi. I think I am detaching the child object here: `List<DetalheRateio> detalheRateiosBd = rateio.getDetalheRateios();`. This object is updated (values) and I set it back to `Rateio` object. Now, how I update on JPA the child object inside EntityHome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the solution. The list of object `DetalheRateio` must be merged (persisted) before update the object `Rateio`. I tought that the object DetalheRateio as a `Rateio` child will be persisted "automatically by JPA. My mistake. So, I merged manually each `DetalheRateio` object. The snipet that I used to do this:

```
List<DetalheRateio> novos = (List<DetalheRateio>) CollectionUtils.subtract(detalheRateios, detalheRateiosBd);
List<DetalheRateio> excluidos = (List<DetalheRateio>) CollectionUtils.subtract(detalheRateiosBd, detalheRateios);
List<DetalheRateio> detalhesAlterados = new ArrayList<DetalheRateio>();

detalheRateiosBd.removeAll(excluidos);
detalheRateiosBd.addAll(novos);

for (DetalheRateio detalheExcluido : excluidos) {
    getEntityManager().remove(detalheExcluido);
}

for (DetalheRateio dRateio : detalheRateios) {
    detalhesAlterados.add(getEntityManager().merge(dRateio));
}

rateio.setDetalheRateios(detalhesAlterados);
setInstance(rateio);
result = super.update();
getEntityManager().flush();
```